# AJAX call works on local but not on server

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, rest

I'm almost ready to deploy an app and I hit a roadblock.

I have a nodejs app (http://sslscanner-ssldecoder.azurewebsites.net/decoder/)

When I run on my local machine, everything works fine. 
But when I deploy it (on Azure), the AJAX call doesn't send the body (I think).

Here is the jQuery call:

```
$("#decoderSubmit").on('click', function() {

        var body = $('#csr').val();
        var csr;
            decode(body, csr);
    });

    function decode(body, csr) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/decoder',
            data: {
                body: body,
                csr: csr
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            timeout: 4500,
            success: callback,
            error: fail


        });

        function callback(data) {
            var csrBody = data.slice(0, 20);
            var certBody = data.slice(0, 12);

            if (!csr) {
                console.log(certBody);
            }
            if (csr) {
                console.log(csrBody);
            }
        }

        function fail(request, status, err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

    }
```

---

And here is the NodeJS Endpoint (/api/decoder):

```
router.route('/decoder')

    .post(function(req, res) {

        let body = req.body.body;
        let csr = req.body.csr;
        decode(body, csr, function(err, result) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            res.json(result);
        });

        function decode(data, type, callback) {
            if (type == 'true') {
                let inFile = randCertFileName();
                var result;
                fs.writeFile(inFile, data, function(err) { // Write the cert to a file
                    if (err) {
                        console.error("Error writing certificate: " + err);
                        return callback(err);
                    }
                });
                execute('openssl req -in ' + inFile + '  -text', function(out) { // Execute the certutil dump command
                    result = out;
                    var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(data).digest('hex');
                    result = result.concat('\n', 'sha1:', hash);
                    hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(data).digest('hex');
                    result = result.concat('\n', 'md5:', hash);
                    fs.unlink(inFile); // Delete the certificate file
                    return callback(null, result);
                });
            } else if (type == 'false') {
                let inFile = randCertFileName(); // Get a random filename for incoming cert
                var result;
                fs.writeFile(inFile, data, function(err) { // Write the cert to a file
                    if (err) {
                        console.error("Error writing certificate: " + err);
                        return callback(err);
                    }
                });
                execute('openssl x509 -in ' + inFile + '  -text', function(out) { // Execute the certutil dump command
                    result = out;
                    fs.unlink(inFile); // Delete the certificate file
                    return callback(null, result);
                });
            }
        }

    });
```

---

One thing I noticed when comparing the headers of the call on the server and the call on localhost is that this additional header is added: 
"X-Powered-By:ASP.NET"

If that is the problem, could you help me understand how to override it?

Any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What happens? What do you see in the console?

Comment: The line "console.log(certBody)" isn't returning anything. It's empty. And the rest of my code depends on the response from the call so nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the 'execute' line and just invoking the callback with a dummy object?  My first suspicion would be the spawned task.

Comment: I have another endpoint that is almost exactly like this one that uses that command without fail. But i'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: It says that it was cancelled. I set it to return an empty string.

Comment: What happens if you cURL the endpoint? Could be that the Azure server isn't setup to accept connections from your computer

Comment: removing irrelevant liens from the code would really help everyone that's trying to help you

Comment: I removed the irrelevant lines from the post.

Comment: @FeifanZ Thanks for this. For some reason, I can connect to most of my other end points except this one. I'm still looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. My ajax call had no problems. I forgot that I was running the app on a windows server, so the OpenSSL command wasn't working.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using a Linux server if at all possible. There's a lot of good tools and tutorials for Linux (Ubuntu is a safe choice)

Comment: Yea, I'm going to switch from azure to AWS